# Save data in Core Data in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, save

I am currently updating an Objective C app into Swift 3. How do I save input data associated with an object passed from a previous table? The Objective C app runs fine, but I cannot work out what the equivalent syntax would be for Swift 3.

The Objective C code is:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(NSString*) strRain;
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
Rainfall *altRainfall = (Rainfall*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

altRainfall.gauge = strRain;
altRainfall.primaryGauge = self.detailItem;
altRainfall.dateRecorded = todaysDate;
altRainfall.sortDate = [NSDate date];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error])
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [error userInfo];
    NSString *errMsg = [dict valueForKey:@"errMessage"];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note" message:errMsg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [alert show];

    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:altRainfall];
}}
```

The Swift 3 code is:

```
    func save(strRain: String) {

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Rainfall", in: coreDataStack.context)!
    let newRainfall = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: coreDataStack.context)
    newRainfall.setValue(strRain, forKeyPath: "gauge")
    newRainfall.setValue(todaysDate, forKeyPath: "dateRecorded")
    newRainfall.setValue(sortDateItem, forKeyPath: "sortDate")


    print(strRain)
    print(todaysDate)
    print(sortDateItem)

    do {
        try coreDataStack.context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

So, how to replace altRainfall.primaryGauge = self.detailItem with something in Swift?

Comment: Why are you converting all of the `newRainFall.someProperty = someValue` lines into `newRainFall.setValue(someValue, forKeyPath: "someKey")`?

Comment: I tried newRainfall.gauge = strRain etc and got errors so switched to the forKeyPath method.

Answer (score 0):

**for saving and updating data.**

```
 func saveToDataBase(data:[TestData]){
        for data1 in data{

            let request:NSFetchRequest<TestData> = TestData.fetchRequest()
            do {
                let count = try managedObjectcontext.count(for: request)
                if count == 0 {
                    // save data according to your requirement.
                    print(data1)
                }else{

                    //if anything you want to update then wright here
                }

            }catch{
                let error  = error as NSError
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

**You can do like this for retrieving data.**

```
func retriveSaveData(){

    let request:NSFetchRequest<TestData> = TestData.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let data = try managedObjectcontext.fetch(request) as [TestData]

        if let str = data.first?.name{
            // Your retrieve data
            print(str)
        }
    }catch{
        let error  = error as NSError
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you. If you went to see coredata manager then i have made sample project. [project sample](https://github.com/tiwariammit/CoreDataManager)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so distressingly obvious! The line I was missing was:

```
newRainfall.setValue(selectedGauge, forKeyPath: "primaryGauge")
```

This associates the data with the name of the gauge passed from the previous view. So obvious I question why I am even still trying to learn. Perhaps it's just to create new neural networks to stave off the onset of senility.